# Style.Top property doesn't last

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a problem with a php page. What I want is a button that can put a table (inserted with php) to change its TOP from 310px to 500px.
The table starts like this:

```
<?php
print('<table id="bloque" style="top:310px;">');
print("<tr>");
print("<th>Código</th>");
?>
```

My script is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nuevo(){
        document.getElementById("bloque").style.top="500px";
    }       
</script>
```

And my button is like this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Nuevo Registro" onClick="nuevo();">
```

When I click on the button, the table goes to Top 500px, but immediately goes back to 310px. Is there a property that I am missing?

Comment: I think your code is correct, what happens is that you are using an input type submit in your code, so what happens is a page refresh. Then your html returns to the first phase. One solution don't use a submit type button.

Comment: You were totally right! Thanx for the answer!!

Comment: Accept the answer or do you want me to put one for you to accept? This way you are helping people in the future, who have the same problem that you had.

Comment: Yes, I don't know where I can accept the answer.

Comment: If you want to accept the answer there is a Check mark click on it. This way you are helping people in the future, who have the same problem that you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is correct, what happens is that you are using an input type submit in your code, so what happens is a page refresh. Then your html returns to the first phase. One solution don't use a submit type button.

Example use:

```
<button id ="button" type="button" onclick="nuevo();">Nuevo Registro</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using on submit and not actual button.
Change your HTML to

```
<button type="button" onclick="nuevo();">Nuevo Registro</button>
```

```js
function nuevo() {
  document.getElementById("bloque").style.top = "500px";
}
```

```css
#bloque {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table id="bloque" style="top:310px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Código</th>
  </tr>
</table>


<button onclick="nuevo();" type="button">Nuevo Registro</button>
```